# SharePoint 2013 Workflow immediately with "Access Denied" message (tried everything)

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a SPD 2013 workflow that is set to start as soon as a new item is created. When I (as a site collection administrator) upload an item to the List, the workflow runs without issue. When a document is uploaded by user `ABC`, we get the following message:

```
Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP Unauthorized to https://sharepoint.my.domain/AP/_api/web/lists(guid'd2eb05c7-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-181f7b444852') Correlation Id: 142269fe-2d26-ada0-b42a-bb415c2bd911 Instance Id: 54a881b3-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-43b2a1cebb4f
```

I've searched the internet and tried a number of the suggestions seen on other sites:

- Added user `ABC` directly to the site (i.e. not through an AD group)
- Made user `ABC` a site collection administrator.
- Deleted the workflow and recreated it.
- Removed user `ABC` from the site, then re-added him.

None of this has resulted in a change in behaviour. What else is left to do?

Comment: If you create a new document library, whether this issue occurs?